# Ubuntu login loop 14.04

Tags: 14.04, login

so i'm new to linux and i installed ubuntu 14.04 on my old laptop lenovo g50 - i3 -8gb - radeon graphics and it was working fine for around 5 days and then soon every time  i tried to login i got stuck in the login loop. Please help.

Comment: also .Xauthority : no such file or directory turns up

Answer (score 1):

Some steps you can take to fix the login loop:

Go to terminal from login screen: 
Ctl Alt F1

login with user-name and password.

Run updates "sudo apt-get update"

Check all applications "sudo apt-get upgrade"

Check all packages "sudo apt-get -f install"

Update grub "sudo update-grub"

Remove all old applications and packages "sudo apt-get autoremove"

Reboot "sudo reboot"

Answer (score 1):

I too have had this problem. I would suggest DnrDevil's answer (updating, removing all old application, etc.) and if that doesn't work, to try the following:

Sometimes, the .Xauthority file doesn't belong to the correct owner (you). To fix it:

1. At the login screen enter runlevel 3 by pressing CTRL+ALT+F3
2. Type `chown 'username':'username' .Xauthority`, replacing the `'username'` with your username.

If this doesn't work, then I would suggest you follow the first answer at this link: [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

I hope this helps!