# Login Failure( redirects to login after enterning password ) in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, login, login-screen, session

I'm  unable to login to my account in Ubuntu. The login Screen appears and I choose me root account, enter the password and press enter. But unfortunately a black screen is displayed for couple of seconds and than I'm redirected to login again and again.
I'm sure my password is right.
Also I can use the guest session. 
 How can I resolve this bug? I don't want to reinstall whole Ubuntu again. That will be my last option. 
 Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

What was the last action you did in your Ubuntu? Most of the time [login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704811/ubuntu-login-loop-14-04) is happening due to some action which didn't completed successfully. 
I experienced login loop due to graphics card driver releated issue as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721633/nvidia-graphics-card-driver-installed-led-to-login-loop)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in case it is an issue due to nvidia graphics card driver issue.

1. Switch to a virtual terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1-6</kbd> and run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xfce4
   sudo service lightdm restart
   ```
2. Select xfce instead of unity and log in.

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge nvida-*
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install prime-indicator
   ```
3. reboot and log into xfce again
4. prime-indicator
5. switch to the intel card (you may have to log out manually)
6. Log in using unity (this will use the intel card).